# writing an app on iOS 5 - backward compatible?

Tags: ios5, backwards-compatibility

Im using iOS5 to write my app. So does that mean it will only run on devices running iOS5 or are these apps backward compatible with other versions of iOS?

If they are not compatible how do I write them so they are?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I actually asked pretty much the same question, and there is a lot of helpful information in the answers to the question (not just the accepted answer either). -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940240/ios-4-for-iphone-4s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your applications build settings you can set the "iOS Deployment Target" variable. In the current SDK this goes down to version 3.0. You cannot use the latest features then, but your app will run on the specified target. Also be sure that you build for armv6 and armv7 architectures when specifying a deployment target lower that 5.0 (but XCode will warn you in that case).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Im new to iSO 5 hence the question.